# R data.table deal with intraday data and ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table

I think data.table likes two columns for intraday timestamp, one for date and one for time. But then how can I plot the time series with ggplot?

```
dt = data.table(timestamp = c('2000-01-01 00:00:00', '2000-01-01 01:00:00','2000-01-02 00:00:00', '2000-01-02 01:00:00'),
            value = c(1,2,3,4))
dt[, date := as.IDate(stringr::str_sub(timestamp, 1, 10))]
dt[, time := as.ITime(stringr::str_sub(timestamp, 11))]

ggplot(dt) + geom_line(aes(x = ???, y = value))
```

Comment: If time is always 00:00, you can skip it and just use date, right? If not, I think you need to convert back to a datetime format for plotting. (I don't use ggplot and so don't know the details.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Frank's comment above, you can convert timestamp to POSIXct format:

```
ggplot(dt %>%
         mutate(timestamp = as.POSIXct(timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))) +
  geom_line(aes(x = timestamp, y = value)) +
  scale_x_datetime() # you can tweak the appearance of x-axis here.
```

(I assumed YYYY-MM-DD format for your date. If it's YYYY-DD-MM or something, just change the format specification accordingly.)

[image]